# How to include files with NetBeans Platform Framework Application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, embedded-resource, netbeans-platform

I have a bunch of .ini files that I wish to include with my NetBeans Platform framework Java application and I do not know how to do that. What I want is to include these files with the default NetBeans Platform framework installer. Also, how do I access these files using Java code?

**Please note that my question is about the NetBeans Platform framework, not NetBeans IDE.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the files to the application Jar.  Access them using the advice seen in the info. page on embedded resources (see tag above).